# Image and videos downloader app with admin panel and user app on Android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, file-upload, admin

I want to create an app on Android studio using java that lets me the developer to have an admin panel app that enables me to upload funny videos and pictures to a database(preferably firebase) and a user app that enables the users to download or stream the uploaded content. I need a hint or a link to a tutorial video that can help.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest in your storage rules to make sure that to write data, the auth's uid or email MUST be yours.

An example in the rules:

```
write: if request.auth.uid == {myID}
```

OR

```
write: if request.auth.email == {myEmail}
```

obviously, substitute them with your actual email.

Then, for the read section, you can either allow all, or only auth users.

```
read: if request.auth != null
```

Comment:  The approach in your snippets, although OP is asking for the Realtime Database and your syntax is for Firestore. Aside from that, in the second snippet is you should also check if the email address is verified. UID doesn't have that risk, which is why the first snippet is preferred.

Comment: Is that true though? While it's tagged realtime-database, the only way to upload videos and pictures is through storage, unless I'm wrong on that.